# Equations for force exerted on each of two cranes by a slanted cargo as a function of the angle it makes with the ground

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

This paper I'm reading on advanced rigging gives me the following picture: there's a cargo connected to two cranes. There are $L$ meters between the two connection points: $A$ meters between the center of mass and connection point (CP) 1, and $B$ meters from the center of mass to CP 2. The vertical distance between the center of mass and CP 1 is $h_1$, similarly $h_2$ for the other side. The cargo weighs $P$ kg and is slanted so that it makes an angle $\theta$ with the ground, like the picture:

[image]

The text states that these are the equations that predict how much force the cargo exerts on each of the cranes

$$F_1 = \frac{P(B cos\theta - h_2 sin\theta)}{L cos\theta + (h_1 - h_2)sin\theta}$$

$$F_2 = \frac{P(A cos\theta + h_2 sin\theta)}{L cos\theta + (h_1 - h_2)sin\theta}.$$

**Question :**

It doesn't, however, say where they came from. Are these commonly used equations? Is there anywhere I can find a proof for them? Are they correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They come from doing moments (sum of torques is zero)

The moment of a vertical force is the force multiplied by the horizontal distance to the pivot point.

For example the horizontal distance of force $F_2$ from $X$ is distance $XY$, see diagram.

$XY$ is found from $L\cos\theta$ (horizontal distance between $V$ and $W$), then by adding the green $h_1\sin\theta$ and subtracting the green $h_2\sin\theta$.

[image]

from moments around $X$

$$F_2 \times XY = P \times d$$

where $d$ is the horizontal distance between CG and $X$.

The formulae seem ok apart from two things.

1. P must be in Newtons (otherwise you need $Pg$)
2. the $h_2 \sin\theta$ on the top of the $F_2$ formula should be $h_1 \sin\theta$